# JMeter - get error when retrieving the Thread Group name

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I tried the following statements in the BeanShell PreProcessor

```
String groupName = ctx.getThreadGroup().getName();
groupName = "${__BeanShell(ctx.getThreadGroup().getName())}"
```

Both return the ERROR

> jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter:
>   Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file:
>   inline evaluation of: ctx.getThreadGroup().getName();

However, they print the Thread Group name correctly.

Comment: I do not observe that error anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good (at least this line), the problem seems to be somewhere else

[image: Beanshell get Thread Group Name]

Going forward you can use the following options to get to the bottom of your Beanshell script issue:

- Put your code inside the [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) like:

  ```
  try {
      String groupName = ctx.getThreadGroup().getName();
  } catch (Throwable ex) {
      log.error("Something went wrong", ex);
      throw ex;
  }
  ```

  This way you will be able to see full error details in *jmeter.log* file
- Add [debug()](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshcommands.html#debug) command to the beginning of the Beanshell script - it will trigger debugging output to JMeter console window

See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more information on JMeter test script issues troubleshooting.